# a function to remove a none value from a stripping code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

```
final_company_name = [clean.strip('\n') for clean in clean_company_name]
```

this is my code that is trying to strip from the information am getting but am having no value among it and have been getting this error,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: What is the data inside `clean_company_name`?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job. Just add `if clean` at the end of your list comprehension.

```py
final_company_name = [clean.strip("\n") for clean in clean_company_name if clean]
```

Edit: Fails if clean is of type bool. Use `if clean and isinstance(clean, str)` like *Sharim Iqbal* mentioned.

Comment: What if `True` is inside the list. You get an error `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'strip'`

Comment: You're right, I totally missed that, but I see, you fixed it already :)

Answer (score 1):

The [@js-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72301700/a-function-to-remove-a-none-value-from-a-stripping-code/72301760#72301760) answer only works, But failed, If there is a `True` keyword or any `int` or `float` type element inside your list, Like `None` is in your list.

```py
final_company_name = [clean.strip("\n") for clean in clean_company_name if clean and isinstance(clean,str)]
```